# Why does caching a logon page that Requires Https, allow it to be accessed without ssl?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, https, forms-authentication

I have a site that is only accessible through https. Everything worked fine, a couple weeks ago I started adding caching to certain sections, so my logon action looked like this:

```cs
[RequireHttps]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Long")]
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    ...
 }
```

And my web.config authentication contains:

```xml
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" requireSSL="true" protection="All" />
```

Everything seemed to still work fine, when you go to the site it would take you to the https logon page, even if you had typed it in as `http//sitename.com`. Lately I noticed that ELMAH had logged a bunch of *The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL.* for the log on page, and I couldn't figure out why.

As it turns out, under certain situations, if you try to go to a page that requires authorization, it will forward you to `http//sitename.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f` not https, however if you just remove the `?ReturnUrl=%2f` page from the url and press enter, it will take you to the secured `https//sitename.com/Account/LogOn`.

Long story short, removing the `[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Long")]` fixes the problem. **So my question is, why would caching that page cause the page to be accessible without ssl?**